# How to "include" a common sbt snippet in another sbt file

Tags: scala, sbt

Let's say I have a common snippet of statements that I find myself having in many projects. Is there a way to "include" a shared sbt snippet inside another (without writing a plugin)?

e.g.

**Snippet (common-mapping.sbt)**

```
mappings in Universal ++= {
  for (f <- (baseDirectory.value ** "*-prod.conf").get) yield {
    f -> f.getName.replaceAll( """(\w+)-prod\.conf""", "$1.conf")
  }
}.toSeq
```

**Project1's build.sbt**

```
... 
include("path/to/common-mapping.sbt")
...
```

**Project2's (build.sbt)**

```
... 
include("path/to/common-mapping.sbt")
...
```

Is there a way to do so? or do I need to write a plugin?

p.s. the projects are not necessarily part of the same root project

Comment: Did you find a way to include?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plugin is designed to solve this problem, so it's the way to go. Plugins are basically a JAR library that are designed to be used for the builds, and not much else. Also take a look at [auto plugins](http://typesafe.com/blog/preview-of-upcoming-sbt-10-features-read-about-the-new-plugins) that'll be out in 0.13.5.